# Excel/VBA/ADO - SQL query not returning correct results

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I am trying to pull Folio IDs that have departure dates of greater than 30, 60, and 90 days (all from the same file). If one of the IDs also has an occurrence with a date that is less than 30 days, I don’t want that ID pulled. 
I also want the date pulled for Folio IDs with a blank (null?) departure date only if that ID also has a departure date greater than 30, 60, or 90 days.

I have tried numerous combinations of left, inner, right, and nested joins (thanks to answers provided to a previous question). I have come close, but for some reason my query is not pulling any of the blank departure dates, even though I know they exist. My query so far is as follows:

```
 sSQL = "SELECT t1.[Folio Type], t1.[Folio ID],t1.[Departure Date],t1.[Folio Total]"
    sSQL = sSQL & " FROM"
    sSQL = sSQL & "  (SELECT [Folio Type], [Folio ID],[Folio Total],[Departure Date]"
    sSQL = sSQL & "   FROM [Individual Folios$B2:O150000] GROUP BY [Folio Type],[Folio ID],[Folio Total],[Departure Date]"
    sSQL = sSQL & " HAVING [Folio Total] <> 0 and [Departure Date] < " & G30E & ") As t1 "
    sSQL = sSQL & " LEFT JOIN"
    sSQL = sSQL & "  (SELECT [Folio Type],[Folio ID],[Departure Date],[Folio Total]"
    sSQL = sSQL & "   FROM [Individual Folios$B2:O150000]"
    sSQL = sSQL & "   group by [Folio Type],[Folio ID],[Departure Date],[Folio Total]"
    sSQL = sSQL & "   HAVING [Folio Total] <> 0 and ([Departure Date] > " & G30E & " or [Departure Date] is null)) as t2"
    sSQL = sSQL & "   on t1.[Folio ID] = t2.[Folio ID]"
    sSQL = sSQL & "   where t2.[Folio ID] is null"
```

I also have a similar query (that tries to accomplish the same thing as the first query) using nested joins. I thought the two queries should pull the same values, but the totals are different:

```
 sSQL = "SELECT t1.[Folio Type], t1.[Folio ID],t1.[Departure Date],t1.[Folio Total]"
sSQL = sSQL & " FROM"
sSQL = sSQL & "  ((SELECT [Folio Type], [Folio ID],[Folio Total],[Departure Date]"
sSQL = sSQL & "   FROM [Individual Folios$B2:O150000] GROUP BY [Folio Type],[Folio ID],[Folio Total],[Departure Date]"
sSQL = sSQL & " HAVING [Folio Total] <> 0 and [Departure Date] < " & G30E & ") As t1 "
sSQL = sSQL & " LEFT JOIN"
sSQL = sSQL & "  (SELECT [Folio Type],[Folio ID],[Departure Date],[Folio Total]"
sSQL = sSQL & "   FROM [Individual Folios$B2:O150000]"
sSQL = sSQL & "   group by [Folio Type],[Folio ID],[Departure Date],[Folio Total]"
sSQL = sSQL & "   HAVING [Folio Total] <> 0 and [Departure Date] > " & G30E & ") as t2"
sSQL = sSQL & "   on t1.[Folio ID] = t2.[Folio ID])"
sSQL = sSQL & " LEFT JOIN"
sSQL = sSQL & "  (SELECT [Folio Type],[Folio ID],[Departure Date],[Folio Total]"
sSQL = sSQL & "   FROM [Individual Folios$B2:O150000]"
sSQL = sSQL & "   group by [Folio Type],[Folio ID],[Departure Date],[Folio Total]"
sSQL = sSQL & "   HAVING [Folio Total] <> 0 and [Departure Date] is null) as t3"
sSQL = sSQL & "   on t1.[Folio ID] = t3.[Folio ID]"
sSQL = sSQL & "   where t2.[Folio ID] is null or t3.[Folio ID] is null"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a series of UNION queries. Each query has its on WHERE clause to restricte the records returned.

Since most of the SELECT is the same I'd use a WITH clause:

```
WITH A AS(SELECT * FROM [FoliosXXX])

SELECT * FROM A WHERE [Departure DATE] <= 30
UNION
SELECT * FROM A WHERE [Departure DATE] > 30 AND [Departure DATE] <= 60
UNION
SELECT * FROM A WHERE [Departure DATE] >= 60
```

You can make the SELECT for A to be a complex/joined/etc. query. Not sure about GROUPing need to add that to the later SELECTs.

A variation is to use UNIONs and in the SELECT use a NOT IN clause to exclude records already processed.

Comment: Jet/ACE SQL Engine which OP uses to connect to Excel workbook does not support window functions. `WITH()` will not work.

Comment: Your right - sort of - WITH above is an SQL function not a Windows function. But you are likely correct that is not support by Jet or other non-SQL Server drivers. The UNIONS may work, just needs more typing.